# How do I access the id parameter from the ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The issue is that id = 5 is already in the URL as `http://localhost:4032/Category/5`. But to pass that value to the ActionLink it seems I have to do this:

```
<td> @Html.ActionLink(p.ProdNo, "Main", "Home", new { id = 5, prodno = p.ProdNo }, null) </td>
```

Which results in the correct URL: `http://localhost:4032/Main/5/1097`

But having to do that doesn't seem very right. I know there must be some clever way to handle this. Unfortunately, it's late in the day and I'm all out of clever.

I tried this:

```
<td> @Html.ActionLink(p.ProdNo, "Main", "Home", new {prodno = p.ProdNo }, null) </td>
```

But ended up with `http://localhost:4032/Main?prodno=1097`.

I tried adding the parameters to the corresponding method in the codebehind but that didn't seem to work either.

So in short, when using an ActionLink how do I get the routevalue already in the URL AND pass in another/new routevalue?

Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Sections", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{prodno}/{instid}/{section}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Pumps", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{prodno}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional  } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Jobs", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Jobs", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Comment: @DotNet.....is Category the Model behind the View that your code is copied from?  If so, does Category.Id = 5?

Comment: I have a viewmodel but yes, the ID does equal 5

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set up the route for your prodno-parameter. Looks like this thread could contain a solution:

[Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Your last example dosent contain a value for the id parameter?

Comment: I know. I was showing the URL it was producing and that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch it from the `RouteData`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    p.ProdNo, 
    "Main", 
    "Home", 
    new { id = ViewContext.RouteData["id"], prodno = p.ProdNo }, 
    null
)
```

Comment: Is this the normal way of handling it?

Comment: The normal way is to use view models. But this could also do the job.