# MVC4: How to control multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)

Experimenting with the MVC4 web api, I defined the following route, in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name:="API Default", 
  url:="api/{systemid}/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
)
```

I changed the controller accordingly

```
Public Class ValuesController
    Inherits ApiController

 Public Function GetValues(systemid As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
     ---
 End Function

 Public Function GetValue(systemid As Integer, ByVal id As Integer) As String
     ---
 End Function
End Class
```

I was looking to format requests uri like

```
http://localhost/api/13/values/5
```

but the only working call is with explicit parameters, as to

```
http://localhost/api/values?id=5&systemid=4
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I was looking for?

Comment: It seems partly a duplicate, there was an error using the wrong class, as pointed out by @cuong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you use the wrong routing class, instead of using Web API routing, you used MVC routing, it should be:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name:="API Default", 
  routeTemplate:="api/{systemid}/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it was that simple ...