# Passing multiple parameters to default action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an app that is just one controller and one action, but I want to pass two values into that action. The end result that I'm looking for is a url that looks like this `http://www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2`

So I was thinking that the routing would look like this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
    );
```

and the controller would look like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id, string name)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But I'm clearly wrong as it doesn't work. Does anyone know if it's possible under the index action?

Just to clarify, I want 2 parameters in the default action. I'm aware it's possible by having something like http://www.example.com/books/parameter1/parameter2/ but I specifically want http://www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To totally omit the `controller` and `action` placeholders in the route you can just remove them. 
(Do not remove it from your default route, better create a new one and place it about the default one)

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{id}/{name}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
    );
```

This route will only work with `Index` action from `HomeController` but not with others.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much for your help. It seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is optional, what your URL would look like when it's not entered, but name is?

```
/Home/Index//name
```

That's obviously invalid.

Consider using the values in the query string instead of part of the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've amended the question. The parameters shouldn't be optional.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14169882/4342522) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12740182/4342522) to solve the problem.
Need two Routes and make sure these routes come above the default MVC route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "with-name",
        url: "Home/{action}/{id}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        //No Optional
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "without-name",
            url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
```