# mvc2 is it possible to add parameter in url level in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using MVC2 in my application. I am passing a token in my url. When I call the controller it's working fine but I need to add one more parameters "Cid=x"

Code:

```
public ActionResult DetailPreferences(VMDetailPreferences vm)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["token"]))
    {
        GetDetails(Request["token"]);
       return View(vm);
    }    
}
```

http://mydomain.com/Api/Al/DetailPreferences?token=12345 but i want to call
http://mydomain.com/Api/Al/DetailPreferences?token=12345&Cid=x

Is it possible to add Cid=x ?

Comment: You can easily add a route which handles the additional parameter. There is an excellent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc) showing you exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

At that point it's too late to add it to the url because the url is already being called.

You could redirect to the url and add on the token, **but I don't think this is what you want**

```
RedirectToAction("DetailPreferences", new {cid = "x"});
```

A better option to access the information on your view is to add it to the [viewdata](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx)

```
ViewData["cid"] = "x";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my case it doesn't work i am passing only one parameter "token",here i am not looking for access that parameter when i pass "token" page load i need go with both parameters in url ...