# How to build url to pass variables in c#

Tags: c#, url

When I try to pass parameters in url I used GET to do so, but I noticed that facebook and some other sites passing variables by building url in different way like this "facebook.com/user1".
I think "user1" is passed and there is no real directory named "user1" in facebook.com base directory.

how to use "mysite.com/user1" instead of "mysite.com/?user=user1" to maintain user id, without creating a directory named "user1" in base directory?

Programming language: C#.
IIS version: 7.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1) Use ASP.NET MVC by using your own Route. For more about ASP.NET MVC, you can refer this:

- [Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)
- [Controller & Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing)

However **I suggest you starting from beginning for the 2nd link**.

2) If you are using a general ASP.NET WebForm, Please use [UrL-ReWriter](http://urlrewriter.net/).
another good torturial at:http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/URL-Rewriting-in-ASP.NET-using-URLRewriter.Net/38861

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the URL as below

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?user=" + USERID
```