# How configure route in ASP.MVC to have more actions in the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

In the ASP.MVC I am developing I neet to have more than one action in the url.

This is an example

```
BaseUrl/Release/1/Milestone/5/Feature/4
```

How can i configure the routes and the action methods to achieve this?

In this case I expected the action Milestone in the ReleaseController is the one that get called, with three input id:

```
public class ReleaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Milestone(int releaseID, int actionID, int secondaryID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thank you @Mati Cicero to pointing me to the right direction. I followed his solution making also url a little more "dynamic".
This is my final code, maybe can be useful also for someone else:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ReleaseSection",
                url: "Release/{releaseId}/{action}/{actionID}/{subAction}/{thirdID}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Release",
                    action = "Index",
                    releaseId = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    actionID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    subAction = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    thirdID = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );


public ActionResult Milestone(int? releaseId, int? actionID, string subAction, int? thirdID)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you really just want one action with multiple parameters.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Can you be more precise? What do you expect from the URL above? Should the Release action be called with parameter 1, after that the Mildestone action with parameter 5 and last the Feature action with parameter 4?

Comment: Yes, but I don't like the idea to use inexpressive url like
BaseUrl/Release/1/5/4

Comment: Added additional information in the question about the expected behavior.

Comment: use traditional query strings `BaseUrl/Milestone?releaseID=1&actionID=5&secondaryID=4`

Comment: @Jonesy I think get parameters are intended as optional. In my case all the IDs are mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this, but did you try the following route?

**Url**: `BaseUrl/Release/{releaseID}/Milestone/{actionID}/Feature/{secondaryID}`

**Defaults**: `new { controller = "Release", action = "Milestone" }`

**Constraints**: `new { releaseID = "\\d+", actionID = "\\d+", secondaryID = "\\d+" }`

The MVC engine should map the route segments to you action's arguments