# How to enable use of both named and unnamed url parameters in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Most likely a very basic question, but still: In an ASP.Net MVC application, how can I enable a controller to respond to URLs that have either named or unnamed URL parameters.

With the following controller:

```
[Route("test/display/{scaleid}")]
public ActionResult Display(int scaleid)
{
    return View();
}
```

I try two URL requests - the first one works, the second one (where I specify the parameter name), doesn't work. Why is this?

```
http://localhost:43524/Test/Display/11
http://localhost:43524/Test/Display/?scaleid=11
```

Comment: Configure Routes in Route COnfig file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make parameter optional:

```
[Route("test/display/{scaleid:int?}")]
public ActionResult Display(int scaleid? = Nothing)
{
    return View();
}
```

2) If url parameter is missing, try to take it from query string:

```
   string scaleid_par = this.Request.QueryString["scaleid"];
   if (!scaleid.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(scaleid_par) ) {
        int.TryParse( scaleid_par, scaleid );
   }
```

Comment: Thanks - when I add "{scaleid:int?}" to the route, then it works. Why is this? Why can I use a named parameter in the URL when I introduce a type constraint on the route, and make it optional?

Comment: Not type needed to fix your code, just set it as optional/nullable (? char). Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The last slash in

```
localhost:43524/Test/Display/?scaleid=11
```

will break the routing for that URL. This should resolve:

```
localhost:43524/Test/Display?scaleid=11
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get an error when taking out the last slash and trying the suggested URL. "Resource not found" for  "/Test/Display"

Answer (score 1):

Because you told ASP, that the URL mapping is "test/display/scaleid".
So in your second test "scaleid" is not defined.

I can not test it at the moment but please try this mapping:
"test/display/{scaleid}?{scaleid}