# How to call action in mvc with dynamic parameters as number of parameter can be less or more?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Suppose  I have an action named "Index" without no parameters in homeController. How we can call the action from url like this "home/index/1/2" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: In my url can have any number of parameter while action will not have any parameter. So how I can call same action with same action name and varying parameters? e.g. need to call Index action, if we have url "home/Index/test1" or "home/index/test1/test2"

Comment: You would need to define multiple routes, or just use query string values

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite number of possibilities, you could have defaulted parameters in your method that can be overridden if necessary...

```
public ActionResult Index(string arg1 = "", string arg2 = "")
{

}
```

Look to see if they have values, work from there...