# How to use Url route url with parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

i have a page with ~/x.aspx with urlmappings :

```
<add url="Home" mappedUrl="~/x.aspx" />
```

what i want is when calling ~/x.aspx?type=y then url still display Home
is there any way to do that

```
<add url="Home" mappedUrl="~/x.aspx" />
 <add url="Home" mappedUrl="~/x.aspx?type=y" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Web Forms, you can use the following tutorial. Basically the "type" could be a list of optional check boxes and the complete URL with parameters could be constructed in your code-behind.

[Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

For MVC, see the following question:

[Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work with mappings in the web.config but apparently  [is not possibly to use wildcards/regex](https://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/navigation/urlmapping.aspx)

But you can do that by overwriting in your Global.asax the method Application_Start

```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            // routing segment variable: {}
            routes.MapPageRoute(null, "home", "~/Pages/x.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute(null, "home/{type}", "~/Pages/x.aspx");
```