# Receive data from ASP.NET MVC url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to the ASP.NET MVC framework. I am trying to get data from url parameters, then from my controller I want to return with ViewBag.

But the problem is, when I type that url in the browser, in debug mode, the data is not being returned correctly. Please have a look at

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

to see debug results. Any idea what's wrong here?

The Url I am using is:

```
http://localhost:60617/CategoryResearch/test/name=john?id=33
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult test(string name, string id)
{
    ViewBag.name = name;
    ViewBag.id = id;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code, your default route is expecting id as parameter and so taking 'name=john' as parameter value. you should create a custome route and use url as http://localhost:60617/CategoryResearch/test/john/33

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing with Multiple Parameters using ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url does not look right to me. 
Try `/CategoryResearch/test?name=john&id=33`.

Answer (score 2):

Your route seems to be setup to pull the `id` from the URL path, which is why it's getting the entire value of the last step in the path ("name=john").

I think you either need to pass the actual id number in the URL path like this:
`http://localhost:60617/CategoryResearch/test/33?name=john`

or you need to move all parameters into the query string:
`http://localhost:60617/CategoryResearch/test?name=john&id=33`