# How to pass a variable number of arguments with different types to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say we have two entities both of which have keys with different number of properties and types (mapped to a database using EF Core)

```
class Order
{
    [Key] int ProductId
    [Key] datetime OrderTime
}

class Product
{
    [Key] int Id
    string Name
}
```

Is it possible to make a controller action method that takes a variable number of arguments with different types like the "params" c# keyword

```
[HttpDelete]
public Task<ActionResult> DeleteItem(params object?[] key)
{
    _repository.DeleteItem(key);
    return NoContent();
}
```

If so, how do I send the arguments using an HttpClient, something like

```
var query = "?productid=0&ordertime=2022-12-10 10:15"
_httpClient.DeleteAsync(query);

var query = "?id=0"
_httpClient.DeleteAsync(query);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do they need to be bound to types? Or can you just use `HttpContext.Request.Query["name"];`?

Comment: @nullforce can you please elaborate?

Comment: You have a controller.  Looks like you are sending a GET from client without a body.  The Task<ActionResult> is the body of the request.  Your query is part of the URL which you added add parameter to the URL by adding a question mark to the URL followed by parameters.  See following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246481/routing-with-multiple-parameters-using-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You can send anything you want to an endpoint and in the controller action do anything you want with the received data. You need to be more specific. But maybe the first question should be: why? You'll create a very dangerous endpoint that's very hard to protect and requires tons of client-side code to make it safe, not even mentioning the code to determine what to do. Normally, you'd create a REST service for such requirements. Or a GraphQL endpoint.

Comment: @jdweng this answers my question, could you repost it as an answer, I will accept it. I think the question should stay as Gert Arnold's comment is valuable too considering that was a bad design.

Comment: The URL is not protected.  To protect the parameters it is better to use HTTPS (secure) where the HTTP Headers and Body are encrypted.  So it is best to put you query either in the Headers or the body.